# How to parameterise Dataset definition filename in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I have a blob storage container folder (source) that gets several csv files. My task is to pick the csv files starting with "file". See example filename below::

**file12345.csv**

The numeric part varies every time.

I have set the "fixed" Container and Directory names in the image below but it seems the File parameter does not accept wildcard "File*.csv". 
[image]

How can I pass a wildcard to the Dataset definition?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that operation in Soure dataset.

Just choose the container or folder in the dataset like bellow:

[image]

Choose the `Wildcard file path` in Source settings:

[image]

The will help you filter the filename wildcard "File*.csv".

Ref: [Copy activity properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#copy-activity-properties):

[image]

Hope this helps.